# SQLAlchemy - How to query from a table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am using a PostgreSQL database and the engine appears to be set up correctly when I created it.

I then use connection = engine.connect() to connect to it.

I then use metadata = MetaData()

When I type s = select ([name_of_my_table]), I get an error message that my table is not defined.

What am I doing wrong? The table exists in the database connected to in the engine.

Comment: In SQLAlchemy you define each table as a class that inherits from `Model`.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/metadata.html#table-reflection